# Why is pandas saving over multiple columns?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

Hi trying to save scraped titles into a csv using pandas

```
def check_for_meta_titles(url):
    try:
        source = requests.get(url).text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(source, features="html.parser")
        title = soup.find("title")
        title = title.text        
        df.at[index,'meta-title'] = title
    except Exception as e:
        print(e,"Error while checking for meta titles.....")


df = pd.read_csv(input_csv)

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    url = row['url']
    check_for_meta_titles(url)
    df.to_csv(input_csv, index=False)
```

Some of the meta titles save fine in the column "meta-title" as expected.

Others save over multiple columns with the first word of the meta title saving in "meta-title" column but every other word in the title saves to a different column

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your code is not reproducible

Comment: The problem of a csv file is that fields are separated with *delimiters*. If you try to write a field containing the delimiter character or a new line, you must use quotes around the field when writing it... and later when you read it back. But I cannot say more without a [mre].

Comment: Thanks, I have edited it should now be reproducible?

Comment: SOLVED.... for anyone else having the same issue my problem was that I did not encode the CSV to utf8:

df.to_csv(input_csv,encoding="utf8", index=False)

This seems to have solved the problem hopefully someone will find this useful in the future